# Tensorflow/Spyder resetting with no error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, ipython, spyder

I'm running keras/tensorflow within Spyder and have some long training sessions with my current model.  I left for the day and when I came back, the ipython terminal seems to have reset itself or something:  prompt back to `In [1]:` and all variables purged. There are no error messages of any kind. The kernel doesn't seem to have fully reset since I can see the history in the ipython terminal.  What might have caused this, and how can I prevent it from happening again?  This is the second time, so it's no fluke.

Comment: Simply run your code using a terminal, something like this:- `python3 PATH_TO_YOUR_CODE_FILE.py` If it stops again, then you know that the problem is either in your hardware or in your code. Maybe your RAM filled up so much that after some time system had to kill those processes. So the best way is closing **all** applications and running code via the prompt.

Comment: I agree with neel, I think the problem is your computer runs out of memory.

Comment: Strange since I can run it for hours of the same loop while I'm here, then it loses it later.  No new memory is (purposely) allocated in the loop, it's just training.  Something like vanishing gradient is possible, but I'd think that would (at worst) result in a divide by zero error or such.